# Razor page Login losing property values after post

Tags: c#, asp.net-identity, blazor, razor-pages, .net-5

I am using the default login razor page setup that .Net gives you after scaffolding. It initially displays everything correctly, but after an invalid login, the value of `ExternalLogins` is forgotten and set to null, which stops my external login button from rendering. I'd like its value to be remembered after a post.
Login.razor.cs:

```cs
namespace Whatever
{
    [AllowAnonymous]
    public class LoginModel : PageModel
    {
        private readonly UserManager<ApplicationUser> _userManager;
        private readonly SignInManager<ApplicationUser> _signInManager;

        public LoginModel(SignInManager<ApplicationUser> signInManager, UserManager<ApplicationUser> userManager)
        {
            _userManager = userManager;
            _signInManager = signInManager;
        }

        [BindProperty]
        public InputModel Input { get; set; }

        public IList<AuthenticationScheme> ExternalLogins { get; set; }

        public string ReturnUrl { get; set; }

        [TempData]
        public string ErrorMessage { get; set; }

        public class InputModel
        {
            [Required]
            [EmailAddress]
            public string Email { get; set; }

            [Required]
            [DataType(DataType.Password)]
            public string Password { get; set; }

            [Display(Name = "Remember me?")]
            public bool RememberMe { get; set; }
        }

        public async Task OnGetAsync(string returnUrl = null)
        {
            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(ErrorMessage))
            {
                ModelState.AddModelError(string.Empty, ErrorMessage);
            }

            returnUrl = returnUrl ?? Url.Content("~/");

            // Clear the existing external cookie to ensure a clean login process
            await HttpContext.SignOutAsync(IdentityConstants.ExternalScheme);

            ExternalLogins = (await _signInManager.GetExternalAuthenticationSchemesAsync()).ToList();

            ReturnUrl = returnUrl;
        }
        //By the time this function is called, ExternalLogins is already null
        public async Task<IActionResult> OnPostAsync(string returnUrl = null)
        {
            returnUrl = returnUrl ?? Url.Content("~/");

            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                //Removed some code for lockout and 2FA for brevity's sake
                var user = await _userManager.FindByEmailAsync(Input.Email);
                if (user == null)
                {
                    ModelState.AddModelError(string.Empty, "Invalid login attempt.");
                    return Page();
                }
                else if (!user.EmailConfirmed)
                {
                    ModelState.AddModelError(string.Empty, "Invalid login attempt. You must have a confirmed email account.");
                    return Page();
                }
                var result = await _signInManager.PasswordSignInAsync(user.UserName, Input.Password, Input.RememberMe, lockoutOnFailure: false);
                if (result.Succeeded)
                {
                    Serilog.Log.Information("User {Email} logged in.", user.Email);
                    if (Url.IsLocalUrl(returnUrl))
                        return LocalRedirect(returnUrl);
                    return RedirectToPage("/");
                }               
                else
                {
                    ModelState.AddModelError(string.Empty, "Invalid login attempt.");
                    return Page();
                }
            }

            // If this far, something failed, redisplay form
            return Page();
        }
    }
}
```

And this is the relevant part of my Login.razor page. I could add error handling to the foreach, but that's not the point:

```html
 <form id="external-account" asp-page="./ExternalLogin" asp-route-returnUrl="@Model.ReturnUrl" method="post" class="form-horizontal">
        <div>
           <!-- Since ExternalLogins is null after post, so I get an error -->
           @foreach (var provider in Model.ExternalLogins)
             {
               if (provider.DisplayName == "Google")
                {
                  <div>
                     Fancy Html code
                  </div>
                }
               else { }
             }
         </div>
 </form>
```

Comment: You should send the current value to the controller on each login attempt and return it to the view from the controller (as part of the model or as Viewdata for example)

Comment: Or as Viewbag would also work

Comment: I mean, I guess that would work, but it's bit janky. Most of the website is blazor but the account stuff has to be razor because of blazor not supporting it yet. Because of that, I'm have barely touched razor in a while, is this forgetting values normal within razor or is there a way to persist the values within the class?

Comment: Actually, @TheMixy I tried using ViewData and it was getting wipped empty too.

Comment: I was not paying attention to the fact that you are using blazor and I'm not sure that viewbag/viewdata are available in blazor as in razor for example. If they are, it should work